# Bluetooth module EGBT-046S vs EGBT-045MS

Tags: microcontroller, bluetooth

I picked up a few of [these bluetooth modules](http://www.dealextreme.com/p/wireless-bluetooth-rs232-ttl-transceiver-module-80711) recently and was trying to figure out a few things.

Aside from the ability to go into master mode,are there any other differences between the EGBT-046S and EGBT-045MS? I see the 045MS has programmable IO and I was kinda hoping that the 046S might have that as it would save me from needing a micro controller for my project (very simple IO going on).

Is the difference between the two really a firmware issue not a device parts/layout?

I found some dual manual containing information for both,but wasn't sure how to be able to tell which version of the device I had as well. I *think* I have the 46S, however Looking at the actual pins on the device, there are connections on the pins that the 45MS has.

[Module(s) Manual](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGwQFjAA&url=http://www.e-gizmo.com/KIT/images/EGBT-04/EGBT-045MS-046S%2520Bluetooth%2520Module%2520Manual%2520rev%25201r0.pdf&ei=4EO2T5x2i9mIAu2T4N4I&usg=AFQjCNEYUQlcoUycX2_lTauJDRZ-tOQFoA&sig2=ER_AXkhtOLiYsjONGJXCwA)

Answer (score 1):

EGBT-045MS and EGBT-046S are generic Bluetooth Modules loaded with SPP ﬁrmware for UART wireless cable replacement functions. The EGBT-045MS can be conﬁgured by the user to work either as a master or slave Bluetooth device using a set of AT commands.

the S means just slave.

Comment: Sorry for the INSANELY long delay, what does SPP mean in this context? What I was wondering is if I can connect to these devices in some way (EGBT-046S) and reprogram them to EGBT-045MS (so I can use the Programmable IO).

Comment: SPP = Serial Port Profile.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Serial_Port_Profile_.28SPP.29